# Iterating specific directories with glob gives me same ordered outputs - is it possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, glob

I would like to ask something about glob function. I use it to iterate over directories which are given in the input in specific order (see list "codes=[...]"). I knew that glob doesn't provide sorted outputs, but when I iterate it based on the specific inputs it seems it works in the order I submitted it.
For better understanding, here is my code:

```
import glob
import yaml

codes=['a1','b1','c1',
       'a2','b2','c2']

#what I want to get from the files
resolutions = []

# get directories
for code in codes:
    directories = glob.glob("../../DATA/{}".format(code))
   
# browse directories, in the directory "a1" is yaml file with name "a1.yaml" and this is what I want to open
    for directory in directories_sorted:
        pdb_code = directory.split("/")[-1]
        yaml_name = directory + "/" + pdb_code + ".yaml"
    
        with open(yaml_name) as stream:
            yaml_content = yaml.load(stream, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
            resolution = yaml_content["Resolution"]
            resolutions.append(resolution)

print(resolutions)
```

And my output looks like this:

```
[3.9, 3.9, 3.6, 3.6, 3.64, 3.32]
```

When I checked the yaml files, it really is that a1 has 3.9, b1 has 3.9, etc and the last in the input c2 has really 3.32. So, it seems that the output is in the same order as my inputs in "codes". Is it possible? I just want to be sure that my results are OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing your ordered input with your output. Yes, you are running glob in a very specific order multiple times. Each instance of glob that you run returns the content of each run in the order you submitted them, but the content within each folder being searched is not sorted, at least not by Python. Each instance of glob returns files in the order that the file system returns them, whether that so happens to be ordered or not.

Comment: Thank you for replying. So, if I teoretically submit 
similar ordered input but with 100 "a, b, c" 's, then I will always get output in a same order as in the submitted input, right?

Comment: The loop is ordered, so the results of the loop will be ordered. Assuming there is one yml per folder, they should remain ordered.